# Nuget restore doesn't add reference to project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

Nuget keeps on not doing what I expect:

Say I got a bunch of references in a packages.config and add that to a newly created project. Then nuget asks me to restore the packages, on answering yes, it only downloads the packages to the packages folder but forgets to add a reference the the project.

How to automatically also add a reference to my project once restored?

Answer (score 8):

Lasse is correct about the NuGet restore. NuGet restore will only download the NuGet packages and extract them to the packages directory.

However with just the package information in the packages.config file there is a way to have NuGet add the references to the project.

1. First restore the NuGet packages.
2. Next open the NuGet Package Manager Console and reinstall the packages using:

   Update-Package -reinstall

The above [-reinstall command](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages) will uninstall and install the packages again and fix any missing references.

There are some limitations with the above command which are documented on the [NuGet site](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages).

Comment: Yeah, I did that, what happens then is that nuget first removes all references,packages and packages.config and as soon as it wants to install it again it quits with an error message that it needs version 3.x (which is not possible for 2013), leaving me without binaries and packages.config

Comment: Sorry about that :( NuGet seems to not be very defensive if any part of the reinstall fails. It should work if you are not using NuGet packages that require NuGet 3. You can also do one package at a time. I believe it could be scripted with a PowerShell script to do reinstall each package one at a time but you may get that package wiped out if NuGet fails.

Comment: No prob, I tried it a few times before already so I didn't get that dissapointed :) I guess it's all 1 by 1 then.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring packages will only download the packages and place them into the right folders on disk.

You get the references when you originally add the nuget packages to the project *the correct way*.

You should not add nuget packages to the projects by modifying the package configuration file, you should add them using the "Add Nuget reference" menu item on the References folder of the project.

Comment: you're saying I have to add 25+ references manually again while I just got a list of packages to be installed. That's not what I expect from a package manager that carries version 2.8